# Browser dimming list element when some child elements are selected but not for one of them

Tags: html, uiwebview, mobile-safari

Given the following html structure:

```
   <ul>
      <li id = "li1" onclick="click('...');">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
            <img class = "track_image" src="..." />
        <div class = "track_title">title</div>
        <div class = "artist_name">name</div>
        <div class = "release_date">date</div>
        <a  class = "visit_website_anchor" href="..."><img id = "visit_website" data-displayed="yes" src=.../></a>
        </div>
        <div class="back" data-displayed = "no">
          <img class = "track_image" src=... />
          <div class = "audio_controls">
        <audio controls></audio>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Then if I click anywhere on the list item apart from the images then it gets displayed in a dimmed state, I'm not adding this so the browser is adding it. However if I click on the track_image class the list item does not get dimmed.
Why does it do it for the other items but not for this one?

Answer (score 0):

The parent `<LI>` element has an `onClick` handler which will change the behaviour of it when a user clicks it in webkit browsers, try applying the following style to it:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

From [Apple Developer library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/articles/standardcssproperties.html):

> "Overrides the highlight color shown when the user taps a link or a
>   JavaScript clickable element in Safari on iPhone.
>
> This property obeys the alpha value, if specified. If you don’t
>   specify an alpha value, Safari on iPhone applies a default alpha value
>   to the color. To disable tap highlighting, set the alpha value to 0
>   (invisible). If you set the alpha value to 1.0 (opaque), the element
>   is not visible when tapped."